# How is this inequality called? (And how to improve this process)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I am reading a book and it mentions the following:

Let $u \in H^1_0(G)$; then $$\lVert u\rVert ^2_{L^\infty(G)} \le C \lVert u \rVert_{L^2(G)}\lVert u'\rVert_{L^2(G)}$$

*Note*: Here $G = (a,b) \subset \mathbb R$ is a bounded interval, $H^1_0(G)$ is the sobolev space of functions null at the boundary of $G$ and $C$ is a constant that depends on $b-a$

How is this inequality called / how to show that it holds? I'm guessing Poincarè inequality plays a role but I am not sure how to deal with the $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{L^\infty(G)}$ norm

P.S. This really seems like something I should be able to find out just by browsing the internet, instead of having to ask here. Is there a way to search the web such that this kind of things show up?

Comment: That second part of the question makes one wonder if a LaTex search engine could be implemented someday.

Comment: Could you define $G$?

Comment: @zuggg You are right, I edited :-)

Comment: For $G \subset \mathbb{R}$ an interval, the proof is easy if you know that every $u \in H^1(G) \supset H_0^1(G)$ has an absolutely continuous representative. Do you already know that?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the hint, I did know that but I didn't think of it.. I tried to write a proof but was not quite able to finish it, do you have another hint? I posted it as an answer :-)

Comment: Under the given hypotheses, $u^2$ is also absolutely continuous. What's the derivative of $u^2$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh thanks! Nice trick :-) Only thing, my constant is equal to $2$ and does not depend on $b-a$.. Can we do better that $2$ then? Or is there something wrong?

Comment: Let $c\in (a,b)$ be a point where $\lvert u^2\rvert$ attains the maximum. You can get to $c$ from both ends of the interval, so you have $$\frac{1}{2}\lVert u\rVert_{L^{\infty}(G)} = \frac{1}{2}\lvert u(c)\rvert^2 \leqslant \min \bigl\{\lVert u'\rVert_{L^2(a,c)}\lVert u\rVert_{L^2(a,c)},\, \lVert u'\rVert_{L^2(c,b)}\lVert u\rVert_{L^2(c,b)}\bigr\}.\tag{$\ast$}$$ Since $\lVert v\rVert_{L^2(a,b)}^2 = \lVert v\rVert_{L^2(a,c)}^2 + \lVert v\rVert_{L^2(c,b)}^2$, at least one of the two products is $\leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \lVert u'\rVert_{L^2(G)} \lVert u\rVert_{L^2(G)}$,

Comment: so that gives you the better constant $\sqrt{2}$, still independent of $b-a$. Playing with the right hand side of $(\ast)$, one may get better bounds depending on $b-a$. But maybe not, I haven't thought much about that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Very cool! Thanks for the help! :D If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it gladly ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Daniel Fischer comments I'm trying to post an answer:

Let $G = (a,b)$

We have that $$\lVert u\rVert_{L^\infty(G)}^2 = \lVert u^2\rVert_{L^\infty(G)} \le \int_a^b 2 |u(t)u'(t)|dt \le 2 \lVert u\rVert_{L^2(G)}\lVert u'\rVert_{L^2(G)}$$

where the first inequality is justified by the fact that $u^2$ is absolutely continuos and $u(a) = 0$ so that we can write $u^2(x) = \int_a^x 2u(t)u'(t)dt$ and the second inequality is just Holder.